# Adding custom chapter tag in footer

Tags: header-footer

I am looking to create an ID tag for each chapter, and add it to the footer. Each chapter will have a different ID number. I tried to create function where the chapter ID could be passed in, but it doesn't seem to be adding to the footer. Any idea on how to do this? I am a little confused on how and where the chapter ID should be input.

```
\newcommand{\chaperID}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\chapterID}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
```

Sample Chapter:

```
\chapter{Creating a project}
\chapterID{ABCD1234}
\input{projectcreate.tex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide working example, not just fragments. I assume, you're using `fancyhdr`. Have used `pagestyle{fancy}` at all? The `\chapterID` is not inserting something really

Comment: The start of each chapter has pagestyle  plain`, you have to alter this style or issue another page style on the start of new chapters or use a different package to handle header and footer or .... Depends on the documentclass, which is unknown.

Comment: Do you want the chapter ID in the footer of all pages for that chapter? Or just the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `fancyhdr` approach with storing the current chapter - ID to a `\@chapid` macro which is then used in `\lfoot`.

However, `\chapter` macros uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the chapter start page, so either change the `plain` pagestyle or kick `\thispagestyle{plain}` out using `\xpatchcmd{...}`, replacing with `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterID}[1]{\edef\@chapid{#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\textit{\@chapid}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\chapterID{ABC}

\blindtext

\chapter{Second}
\chapterID{DEF}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On could redefine `\chapter` to provide an mandatory 3rd argument that is meant to be the chapter id

Comment: Na, no extra `m` arguments. This is deviating from the standard mentioned in every tutorial.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Extra arguments are nice :-P